# Apache2 php parse error on server but not local machine, 7.2.3 to 7.2.4 issue?

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, lamp

I am deploying a laravel project to a droplet. I have everything seemingly set up correctly but I am getting the following error in the log when I go to the website:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /var/www/public_html/studystation/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php on line 499`

The line in question is as follows

`public function getCharset(): ?string`

php 7.2.3 was the version used in development. Checking with `php -v` the server is running 7.2.4. Could this difference be causing the parse error or could this be from improper setup? I'm also unsure how to go about setting up the older php 7.2.3 on the server to test the problem myself. I'm quite new to server setup and configuration.

Comment: Are you _entirely sure_ you're using PHP 7.2.4 on your droplet? Nullable type hints were [added in PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php). It sounds like you've got an older version. (And generally speaking it's unlikely that a minor point release would introduce an incompatible change. Nothing should break from 7.2.3 to 7.2.4. But it's still a good idea to develop using the exact same version of PHP you're targeting on your server.)

Comment: Instead of using `php -v`, this time I went to the `website/info.php` page and  found that the server was actually running php 7.0 which comes on Ubuntu 16.04. I was able to disable php 7 and fix the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and it was PHP version issue. I install the PHP 7.1 on the server and enable it by running this command

`a2enmod php7.1` and  `php -v` return `7.1 version` but on browser by checking with `phpinfo() function` on a file it shows PHP 7.0.

I miss to disable the php7.0 and I did it by running:

`a2dismod php7.0`

and it did the trick.

P.S: You can use PHP versions which you installed, In my case I migrated from PHP 7.0 to 7.1

Comment: Thanks man, I had same issue and you helped me. This worked for me.